# Removing detergent smell from clay/earthen pot

Tags: water, smell

I used detergent to clean a newly bought clay pot. Kept water in it for around 5 hours, To my surprise I am now drinking perfume :(.

How do I now remove this strong detergent smell. I tried coating it's internal surface with lemon juice over night. Washed it 10times. But no avail. Is there a way I can get rid of the smell?

[image]

Comment: i would never drink out of a clay pot ... the clay could easily have toxic ingredients

Comment: This question does not appear to be about home improvement within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the oven? Low setting for an hour or so might work.

Answer (score -1):

First of all it was a good decision that you opt for clay pot for drinking water.

It is always advisable to not to use any detergent, soap or any chemical for washing clay pot. Since you have already use detergent so you have three options:

1. Use the pot for growing plants and buy a new fresh clay pot
2. Or you can try this:

   1. Collect some fresh rice washed water everyday and pour it into the pot
   2. Keep it for 1 day and rinse it gently next morning,
   3. Repeat this process for total 15 days
3. Or you can also use warm water + baking soda:

   1. Pour it in pot and keep it for 1 day
   2. Next day rinse and wash the pot repeat this process again for 15 days.

After 15 days, if it's good to go then start using it otherwise use this pot for planting and gardening.